# Running Mocha tests in Webstorm

Tags: testing, mocha.js, webstorm

I'm running Mocha tests for React in Webstorm's terminal window using the following NPM start command:

```
"tsc && mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test_helper.js \"test/**/*.@(js|jsx)\" --watch --watch-extensions js,jsx,tsx"
```

How do I create a Webstorm Mocha configuration so that I can run tests in Webstorm's test window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add a configuration for Mocha:

`Run -> Edit Configurations -> Press "+" -> Select "Mocha".`

Fields of the form:

**Node interpreter:** your_node_executable_path

**Working directory:** root_path_of_your_app

**Mocha package:** mocha_path (normally within your `node_modules` folder).

**Test directory:** root_path_of_your_app **\test**

By default Mocha looks the tests inside `test` folder and there, it tries to run `test.js`.

All the Mocha commands (`--compilers`, `--require`, etc) can be included in `mocha.opts`. Mocha tries to read this file in `\test\mocha.opts`.

`mocha.opts` requires one command per line.