# Run typescript tests for Mocha in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js, webstorm

I follow the instruction on this page:

[Running Mocha tests in Webstorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35979110/running-mocha-tests-in-webstorm)

to run Mocha tests in WebStorm, but my tests are written in TypeScript (saved in .ts), I was wondering how do I run these?  Here is an example:

```
describe("My Tests", () => {
    it("Test #1", () => {
        let nluConfig: any = {
            "Provider" : "LUIS",
            "Model" : {
                "ID" : "aaa",
                "Secret" : "bbb"
            }
        };
        debugger;
        let result:any = CNluFactory.getNluProvider(nluConfig);
        expect(result).to.be.an.instanceof(CLuis);
    });
});
```

Here is how I currently configured WebStorm to run my tests:

[image]

This is the error I get when I try to run:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Repository\Main\node_modules\nyc\bin\nyc.js --reporter=lcovonly --report-dir=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\mocha-intellij-coverage- C:\Repository\Main\node_modules\mocha\bin\_mocha --ui bdd --reporter "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2017.2.1\plugins\NodeJS\js\mocha-intellij\lib\mochaIntellijReporter.js" --recursive C:\Repository\Main\src\test
No test files found
```

I assume it couldn't recognize the TS file in my test directory?

Comment: Either transpile them or use something like ts-node with `node_modules/.bin/mocha --compilers ts:ts-node/register ./tests/**/*.ts`

Comment: Right, but how do I add that in WebStorm?

Comment: in the blank field called mocha options

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Mocha can't run typescript files natively; you need to either pre-compile them and pass the generated `.js` files to test runner, or compile them on-the-fly using [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node), for example (`--require ts-node/register/transpile-only` or the now [deprecated](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation) `--compilers ts:ts-node/register/transpile-only`):

[image]

Of course, you need to make sure to install `typescript` and `ts-node` modules next to `mocha`

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Comment: `--compilers` is [now deprecated](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation). Use `--require ts-node/register` instead

Comment: @chazsolo It did not work with `--require ts-node/register` (it does for single files though).

Comment: Actually, use `-require ts-node/register/transpile-only` for a significantly faster experience, as this avoids the Typescript type checking which you don't need.

Comment: The above mentioned compilation always fails in my case. How does the mocha build differ from the ng build? what configuration is used?

Comment: I also needed to add `--extension ts`, otherwise I got the errors that there were no tests found.

Comment: @ArnoldDaniels Yes - my complete entry for 'extra mocha options' is: ```--require ts-node/register --extension ts```

Comment: I get "unknown file extension ts" no matter what.